# Windows Time not updating after reboot

Tags: windows, boot, time, reboot

Yesterday, for the first time, my laptop blackened out and I noticed it's base was pretty heated up. I Googled the cause and came to know that some laptop shuts itself down to prevent damage to the hardware due to overheating.

Today, I tried to power-on my laptop and it booted up normal, except for the fact that Windows Time wasn't showing the current time, it was still showing the last boot-time (Yesterday's). I went to the services panel of the Windows, located "*Windows Time Service*" and set it to **auto-boot**, as it was **disabled** in the start-up previously.

I shut down my computer and started it again after 15 minutes but it was again showing the last boot time (15 minutes ago). I think, something is broken when the laptop shut down due to overheat, as it's not taking into account of the time when it's turned-off. Do I need to change CMOS Battery? Waiting for the reply, thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Reset all time-related settings to default and reboot. If it doesn't work it's probably the CMOS battery, although that's a bit odd. You can replace it, or, alternatively, use internet time instead of local time.

Click on the clock to bring up the calendar and click on `Change date and time settings`. Select the `Internet Time` tab and sync it with `time.windows.com` or `time.nist.gov`.

P.S.: Check the BIOS time to make sure it's the CMOS battery fault.